# (Angular2/4/5/6) How to validate length of international phone numbers according to country

Tags: angular, validation, angular6, phone-number

is there a library/service class available to validate international mobile numbers individually? E.g. Singapore mobile number must have 8 digits, China 11 digits, etc. Currently I'm using ng4-intl-phone in reactive form format to allow user to input their mobile numbers.

The validations should appear according to each country and not a general check for international phone numbers like the number is from 3 to 14 digits (It was what I was using previously).

Appreciate your help!

**UPDATE**

I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-international-phone-number for the time being instead. I'll still leave those answers below if anyone needs to use them for reference!

Comment: I have used http://smoshysmosh.github.io/ng-intl-tel-input/ in several project successfully. Hope it will solve your problems. If you need I can provide some sample code.

Comment: Hey Janith, thanks for your help, but I'm looking for angular 2/4/5/6 solutions.. do you happen to have sample code for it? Thanks!!

Comment: Please check my answer. If it solve your problem please mark it as answer and vote me up ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my custom solution. It works fine on my solutions.

Please install intl-tel-input to your project

```
npm i intl-tel-input --save
```

Then create a `IntlTelInputComponent` component as follows.

**intl-tel-input.component.ts**

```
import {
  AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Input, Output, ViewChild, forwardRef, Renderer
} from '@angular/core';
import 'intl-tel-input';
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor, } from '@angular/forms';

export interface ITimeInputFieldChanged {
  value: string;
  extension: string;
  numberType: string,
  valid: boolean;
  validationError: any
}

export const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => IntlTelInputComponent),
  multi: true
};

const noop = () => {
};

@Component({
  selector: 'intl-tel-input',
  templateUrl: './intl-tel-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./intl-tel-input.component.scss'],
  providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})

export class IntlTelInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() fullValue: string;
  @Output() fullValueChange = new EventEmitter<ITimeInputFieldChanged>();
  @Input() id: string;
  @Input() intlOptions = {
    initialCountry: 'no',
    formatOnDisplay: true,
    separateDialCode: true,
    onlyCountries: ['no', 'be']
  };
  @Input() value: string;
  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Output() valueBlur = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Output() valueFocus = new EventEmitter();
  @ViewChild('intlInput') intlInput: ElementRef;

  private extension: string;

  private onTouchedCallback: () => void = noop;
  private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = noop;

  constructor(
    private _renderer: Renderer) { }

  onInputChange(value: string) {
    const intlInput = jQuery(this.intlInput.nativeElement)
    this.value = value;
    this.valueChange.emit(value);
    this.fullValue = intlInput.intlTelInput('getNumber');
    this.extension = intlInput.intlTelInput('getSelectedCountryData').dialCode;
    const validationErrorCode = intlInput.intlTelInput('getValidationError');
    let validationMessage = 'VALID';
    switch (validationErrorCode) {
      case 1:
        validationMessage = 'INVALID_COUNTRY_CODE'
        break;
      case 2:
        validationMessage = 'TOO_SHORT'
        break;
      case 3:
        validationMessage = 'TOO_LONG'
        break;
      case 4:
        validationMessage = 'NOT_A_NUMBER'
        break;
      case 5:
        break;
      default:
        validationMessage = 'VALID'
        break;
    }
    this.fullValueChange.emit({
      value: value,
      extension: this.extension,
      numberType: intlInput.intlTelInput('getNumberType'),
      valid: intlInput.intlTelInput('isValidNumber'),
      validationError: validationMessage
    });
    // this.writeValue(this.fullValue);
  }

  onBlur(value: string) {
    this.valueBlur.emit(value);
  }

  onFocus() {
    this.valueFocus.emit();
  }

  writeValue(value: any): void {

    if (value && (value !== this.value)) {
      this.fullValue = value;
      setTimeout(() => {
        const phoneInput = jQuery(`input#${this.id}`);
        phoneInput.intlTelInput('setNumber', this.fullValue);
      }, 100);
    }
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => any): void { this.onTouchedCallback = fn; }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }

}
```

**intl-tel-input.component.html**

```
<input #intlInput class="form-control"
[appIntlTelInput]="intlOptions"
[id]="id"
[ngModel]="value"
(ngModelChange)="onInputChange($event)"
(blur)="onBlur($event)"
(focus)="onFocus()"
>
```

**intl-tel-input.component.scss**

```
:host /deep/.intl-tel-input{
    display: block;
    .country-list{
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
}
```

**intl-tel-input.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'intl-tel-input';
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appIntlTelInput]'
})
export class IntlTelInputDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input('appIntlTelInput') appIntlTelInput: any;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // jQuery.fn.intlTelInput.loadUtils('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.12/js/utils.js');
    // jQuery.fn.intlTelInput.loadUtils('/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js');
    jQuery.fn.intlTelInput.loadUtils('assets/js/utils.js');
    jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).intlTelInput(this.appIntlTelInput);
  }
}
```

**Usage inside a form**

```
 <intl-tel-input formControlName="Mobile" ></intl-tel-input>
```

Hope this will solve your problem. It can validate any international mobile number as you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll try to work it out and get back to you :) Meanwhile I shall upvote this for the time being.

Comment: hey janith! I've updated the component name to app-intl-tel-input according to angular requirements. Currently there's an error saying appIntlTelInput doesn't exist.. any idea? Thanks! :)

Comment: @iBlehhz sry, I've missed intl-tel-input.directive.ts file. Please check the updated code.

Comment: @iBlehhz is this did not help to solve your requirement ?

Comment: Sorry, I had issues running the code, e.g. forwardRef not supported, component naming error and appIntlTelInput was still not detected although I imported the directive in my modules.ts. Realised https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-international-phone-number-fix worked better for me, but nevertheless, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @JanithWidarshana Can this be done without jQuery ?

Comment: It will possible if you find a Typescript definition for `intl-tel-input` or you will have to write it.

Comment: @iBlehhz, I am also try to import npmjs.com/package/ngx-international-phone-number-fix library in my project.. Its working fine. But i need to get the seperate value of country and phone number. right now its getting together.. then its not validating phone number based on country code.. Is there any module to do this???

Comment: hey @Rekha, sorry I'm not sure about it, might want to open it as a separate issue!

Answer (score 2):

I have used [libphonenumber-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libphonenumber-js) in my angular 6 project and it works perfectly fine.